# Powershell with -noexit does not write errors to stderr

Tags: powershell

If I have a powershell script the causes an error, I cannot get the error written to stderr if I use -noexit

For example if I have the following script foo.ps1

```
Get-Process none
```

If run this without -noexit the error is written to stderr

```
PS E:\Play>powershell -file .\foo.ps1 2>Error1.txt
```

If I use the -noexit param the error is not written to stderr

```
PS E:\Play>powershell -noexit -file .\foo.ps1 2>Error2.txt
```

What do I have to do to get the error written to stderr when using -noexit?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I have a script that uses FileSystemWatcher to watch for files being created, so I want to start it with -noexit. I want to capture stderr to a file, but have not be able to do this.

Comment: As I haven't been able to get this to work, I have used Try/Catch which allows be to trap all exceptions and log them appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Why do you run `powershell` from PowerShell prompt? Just use

```
PS E:\Play>.\foo.ps1 2>Error1.txt
```

or (see [Understanding Streams, Redirection, and Write-Host in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/))

```
PS E:\Play>.\foo.ps1 *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath Error1.txt
```

To run above statements from `cmd.exe` command prompt, you need to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) some characters to be survived into the powershell (note all `^` carets):

```
E:\Play>powershell .\foo.ps1 2^>Error1.txt
```

or

```
E:\Play>powershell .\foo.ps1 *^>^&1 ^| Tee-Object -FilePath Error1.txt
```

Omit `-file` switch and use e.g. `-NoExit` from command prompt, see `powershell /?`.